# Limiting CPU usage with SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, windows-server-2012-r2

We're running our SP2013 app box on a VM (not my preference, but it's what I have) and when the search component or timer service spikes to 100% CPU usage, it's pegging out the whole VM farm.

I'm troubleshooting the high usage, which is a fairly known issue with SharePoint. What I'm asking in this question, however, is if there's a way to limit the % of CPU used by a timer job and/or service component. So far several google searches have come up empty, with nearly every result I've checked so far trying to troubleshoot the high usage instead. I just want to cap the sucker off.

The only way I know of is to hard-code an upper limit for the service accounts in the registry. This would prevent any services run by that account from using more than X percent of the CPU. I'd rather find a solution within SharePoint (or even Windows Server 2012) that doesn't require a registry edit.

SharePoint 2013 introduced a lot of changes behind the scenes, and I haven't caught up with all of them yet. I'm hoping there's a way in Central Admin to tweak this.

EDIT: The two services that are consistently consuming high CPU are the search component & the timer service. I've lowered the priority for both and changed the search to "Reduced" performance, but I'd still like to set an upper limit for them if possible.

Comment: do you know exactly which service consuming the CPU...sharepoin time,search host controller etc...their are couple of services you can limit it.

Comment: What VM Host are you using?  Hyper-V, VMWare, etc?  Many VM Hosts have an option to limit the CPU usage to a certain percent of CPU resources or limit to a certain number of cores.

Comment: That's a good idea, James - I'll check with my boss (he handles the VM stuff).

Comment: FYI - the problem went away once we added additional servers to the farm and delegated search to a different box than content.